# How to print a binary value(1010) into decimal value(10) in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gdb

I want to print the decimal value of 1010 in `gdb`,
but it prints the result as it is what I gave last.

```
(gdb) 
(gdb) p/d 1010
$1 = 1010
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GDB's `p`[`rint`] command prints the value of the expression you provide, which is interpreted in the source language of the program being debugged.  In C, your `1010` is a decimal literal, not a binary literal, so your basic problem is that you are giving GDB bad input.

Standard C has no support for binary literals, but GNU C supports them as an extension.  The format is a binary digit string preceded by `0b` or `0B`, which you'll probably recognize as analogous to the standard format for hexadecimal literals.  GDB recognizes this form.

Since `print`'s default output radix for numbers is decimal, you don't need to specify an output format.  Just use the command

```
p 0b1010
```